# How can you leverage the benefits of an older spouse's retirement account?

Tags: united-states, ira, roth-ira, capital-gains-tax, marriage

Can a marriage with a large age gap and a young high-earning spouse benefit from, for example, a Roth IRA?

Let's say Jack and Jill are married. Jill is 50 and makes $25,000/year while Jack is 25 and makes $125,000/year. Neither have established retirement accounts. Jill will retire in 10 years and withhold collecting Social Security.

What can they do to leverage Jill's IRAs (and 401(k))? Is there a particular strategy to maximize tax-free investment growth, either as a lump sum or as monthly distributions, once Jill turns 59-1/2?

Comment: Are the retirement funds in traditional funds or Roth funds?

Comment: There aren’t significant funds in either, but I am wondering if there would be a good strategy. I am assuming that, if they file jointly, more funds in a Roth would be wiser if they intend to withdraw some or all when Jill retires.

Comment: If the income isn't needed, then Jill can simply allow the IRA/401(k) to grow until the couple needs income or Jill reaches 70-1/2 and starts having to take required minimum distributions.  There's nothing at all that has to be done at 59-1/2.

Comment: The two of you make too much income to make pre-tax IRA contributions, but you're under the Roth IRA limit.  You can both make Roth IRA contributions and Jill can make larger contributions due to the catch-up provision.  Both of you should be making retirement plan contributions.